# google chrome extension for manipulating browsing history

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-history

I'm thinking of developing a Google Chrome extension for the first time; no previous experience. The extension I have in mind must be able to look at a user's browsing history and provide the URL of the earliest instance they visited a certain website, or any subdirectory within that website.

For example, a user's browsing history could be:

```
8:58 - http://mysite.com/page/page1.html
8:59 - http://mysite.com/test/index.php
9:00 - http://google.com
9:01 - http://google.com/?q=mysite
9:03 - http://mysite.com/this/info.html
9:04 - http://mysite.com/this/info2.html
9:05 - http://mysite.com/this/info3.html
9:06 - http://facebook.com
```

In this case, let's say the app is looking for instances of visiting http://mysite.com or any subdirectory. (This would be specified in the extension code itself; it's not set by the user.) The extension will look for the most recent "group" of visits to http://mysite.com, which is in this case:

```
9:03 - http://mysite.com/this/info.html
9:04 - http://mysite.com/this/info2.html
9:05 - http://mysite.com/this/info3.html
```

From this group, it will pick the earliest of the entries, and display that URL, which in this case is:

```
9:03 - http://mysite.com/this/info.html
```

Been looking at Google's documentation on working with History in extensions (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history.html), but I don't think what I'm looking for is on that documentation page...

Wondering if anyone could give me a push in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with `history.search` in combination with `lastVisitTime` of `HistoryItem`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any history function available to your extension are listed here:
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history.html

If they aren't you won't be able to access them. There isn't an undocumented history API for chrome extensions.

You'd probably want to do something like this:

```
var siteToSearch = 'facebook.com';
chrome.history.search({text: siteToSearch, callback: function(results) {
    //Iterate through the `results` array of `HistoryItem` objects
    //Look for lowest value of `lastVisitTime` OR call `chrome.history.getVisits` with
    //`results[i].url` and then check the returned `VisitItem` for the `visitTime` property
}})
```

You might want to use a regular expression for matching the URL of the site you are searching for with the result in the browsers history.

Comment: The link in this answer is broken now.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Google moved the documentation at [this link](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/history/)

and the snippet included in the old answer can be used by doing:

```js
const siteToSearch = 'facebook.com';
chrome.history.search({text: siteToSearch}, callback: function(results) {
    //Iterate through the `results` array of `HistoryItem` objects
    //Look for lowest value of `lastVisitTime` OR call `chrome.history.getVisits` with
    //`results[i].url` and then check the returned `VisitItem` for the `visitTime` property
}})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try and reference to this chrome extension in github, which allow you to use browser address bar to search keywords, which will automatically search against your browser history and give you suggestion

[github - history-as-bookmark](https://github.com/gaoqing/history-as-bookmark)

[Chrome webstore - history as bookmark](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-as-bookmark/mfbdcpljldfodjopfhbafaipgmfgalbl?hl=en-GB&authuser=0)